# Google Sheet function to lookup value in A1 for a match in B10:B100 and return the value in each row of that column until it finds the text exit

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a port configuration of a router in B10:B100. I have the specific port listed in A1 that I'm looking for. The output is not sorted alphabetically in column B and can not be as it wouldn't output correctly. Because there are multiple ports and their configs which are not all equal rows in value I want cell C1 to display the matched port looked up in Column B and give the value of the row below it. Then repeat this process until it finds the word exit.

```
   A (lookup value)              B (data column)                           C (output column)
1  port 1/1/2                    port 1/1/1                                port 1/1/2
2                                description test-port                     shutdown
3                                speed 100                                 exit
4                                autonegotiate
5                                exit
6                                no shutdown
7                                port 1/1/2
8                                shutdown
9                                exit
10                               port 1/1/3
11                               description my-laptop
12                               speed 1000
13                               no auto negotiate
14                               hold-down 50
15                               no shutdown
16                               exit
```

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,xmatch(A1,B10:B100), Λ,index(B:B,9+Σ),
     offset(Λ,,,xmatch("exit",Λ:B100)))
```

[image]

`logic`: *search for `port 1/1/2` in B10:B100 → get the cell address → use it to search for first `exit` from below the found address*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=LET(α,B10,Ω,B100,γ,XLOOKUP(A1,α:Ω,α:Ω),γ:XLOOKUP("exit",γ:Ω,γ:Ω))
```

[image]

## Explanation

Same formula with clearer variable names:

```cpp
=LET(start_of_range,B10
     end_of_range,B100,
     match,XLOOKUP(A1,start_of_range:end_of_range,start_of_range:end_of_range),
     match:XLOOKUP("exit",match:end_of_range,match:end_of_range))
```

`match` is the reference to the first cell in `start_of_range:end_of_range` in which the value in `A1` is located

```cpp
match ← XLOOKUP(A1,start_of_range:end_of_range,start_of_range:end_of_range)
```

We then use this reference as the start of a new range that ends at the next occurrence of `"exit"`

```cpp
match:XLOOKUP("exit",match:end_of_range,match:end_of_range)
```

We can't in general create ranges like this, but [`XLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12405947?hl=en) is a special function that returns a reference (i.e. value & location) rather than a simple value.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works exactly as I needed it. Seeing my output is it possible for the start of range and end of range being able to support showing everything excluding the match. Since some ports can have multiple "exit" comments I made a match on "port"&"*". I want the 1st and last lines removed.

'port 1/5/8'
'port 1/5/8'
'description "Link-to-PHNXAZCRT1A-P-AL-0994-H1-SLOT2/1-PORT2"'
'ethernet'
'mode network'
'encap-type dot1q'
'mtu 2106'
'network'
'exit'
'hold-time down 100'
'no autonegotiate'
'egress-rate 1000000'
'exit'
'no shutdown'
'exit'
'port 1/6/1'

Comment: For some reason this match isn't working either: =LET(start_of_range,D73,end_of_range,D1177,match,XLOOKUP(G70,start_of_range:end_of_range,start_of_range:end_of_range),match:XLOOKUP("port*"),match:end_of_range,match:end_of_range))

For putting in this makes it work but I don't want to have to type in the port number just a wild card match on port*: =LET(start_of_range,D73,end_of_range,D1177,match,XLOOKUP(G70,start_of_range:end_of_range,start_of_range:end_of_range),match:XLOOKUP("port 1/6/1"),match:end_of_range,match:end_of_range))

Comment: The example I gave was using cells A1 for the look up but on my actual sheet it is G70, the data on my example was B10:B100 but on my actual sheet it is D73:D1177, and on my actual sheet the output formula is in G71. You can keep the values the same as my example and the way you wrote the code previously. I just wanted you to know why it's different in my post.  Thanks

Comment: `port 1/5/8`
`port 1/5/8`
`description "Link-to-PHNXAZCRT1A-P-AL-0994-H1-SLOT2/1-PORT2"`
`ethernet`
`mode network`
`encap-type dot1q`
`mtu 2106`
`network`
`queue-policy "20110"`
`exit`
`hold-time down 100`
`no autonegotiate`
`egress-rate 1000000`
`cfm-loopback priority high`
`exit`
`no shutdown`
`exit`
`port 1/6/1`

Comment: Sorry I keep trying to past the lines in a way they will display correctly and they don't.  But ultimately I just want to remove the first line it matched on which is port 1/5/8 in my live sheet and once it finds a wild card match on port it stops but doesn't display the port 1/6/1 .  So the first line of the output should be 'description" and the last output should be the last exit instance. Thanks again @Z.. ko-fi.com/zziad

Comment: @cyberjax21, please share a sample sheet where you illustrate the issue and the desired result. You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)